# Why does this function returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, spread

I want to check if one of arguments equal `3`.
If it does i want to return true but i get `undefined`.
Why is that ?

```
function isThree(...args){
  args.forEach(val => {
    if(val === 3){
      return true;
    } else{
      return false;
    }
  })
};
console.log(isThree(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: Because the function returns nothing.

Comment: you aren't returning anything from `isThree`

Comment: look at `Array.prototype.find`

Comment: what should i return then ?

Comment: Use `return args.some` instead of `args.forEach`

Comment: @Fraction Or `includes` or even simply `indexOf`

Comment: because returning from forEach does nothing. There are better ways of doing the check. includes(), indexOf(), some()

Comment: Did you try to define result = true in the first "if" and result = false in "else" and at the end of the function, you return "result" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get `undefined` is because the function `isThree()` doesn't return anything. The two returns in your function return from the anonymous function inside `foreach()`.

I think your function tries to determine if there's a value `3` in the array. There is already a function for that: [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Your function could be:

```
function isThree(...args) {
  return args.includes(3);
};

console.log(isThree(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a for loop which creates a new scope but is not executed in a separate function, forEach is executed in a separate function. I.e., returning from within a forEach handler won't return from the outer function as well.

```js
let x = () => {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(v => {
    console.log(v); // 1 2 3
    return v;
  })
  return 0;
};
console.log(x()); // 0
```

```js
let y = () => {
  for (let v = 1; v <=3; v++) {
    console.log(v); // 1
    return v;
  }
  return 0; // never reached
};
console.log(y()); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a value from the `forEach` function, but that doesn't mean you're returning a value from the `isThree` function. Also, try the `filter` function to find if there *is* a match for the number you're looking for.

Try this:

```
function isThree(...args){
  return args.filter(val => {
    if(val === 3){
      return true;
    }
  }).length > 0;
};
console.log(isThree(1,2,3,4,5));
```

In the previous example, I'm using `filter` to return every instance of the array in which the condition is met (in this case, `val === 3`). Returning `true` appends the result to an empty array, so the operation's response will be an array with every instance that met the condition. So by comparing the array size to `> 0` I can find out if any element met the criteria.

You can even reduce the function further by using the shorthand `args.filter(val => val === 3)`:

```
function isThree(args){
  return args.filter(val => val === 3).length > 0;
};

console.log(isThree(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Or, you can simplify further by using the prototype function `some`, which checks if any element of the array meets the criteria:

```
function isThree(args){
  return args.some(val => val === 3);
};

console.log(isThree(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here about else statement because if `if statement` doesn't find, so obviously it will go for `else statement`, and here is a loop, so need to fix the loop

```
for(let a = 0; 10 > a; ++a )
{
   if( a === 3) console.log('We\'re done'); // I expect only this not else statement

   else console.log('Not found');
}
```

Output:

```
"Not found"
"Not found"
"Not found"
"We're done"
"Not found"
```

in the above example you see, a lot of times we make this mistake, **Now Solve this problem**

```
for(let a = 0; 5 > a; ++a )
{
   if( a === 3) 
    {
      console.log('We\'re done');
      return true; // I expect only this not else statement
    }

}

 console.log('Not found');
 return false;
```

I hope it'll give you an idea about how to solve the unexpected code in the loop;

**Always happy to assist!**